# LISTAGG retornando valores repetidos

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

Tenho uma consulta que fiz concatenação de vários registro usando uma determinada chave.

Todavia ele traz alguns valores repetidos como resultado.
Abaixo um exemplo de uma consulta:

```
SELECT PEH.PN,
LISTAGG (PEH.AC_TYPE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PEH.AC_TYPE DESC) AS 
"EFETIVIDADE"
FROM
ODB.PN_EFFECTIVITY_HEADER PEH
GROUP BY PEH.PN;
```

Que traz como resultado:

```
PN | Efetividade

39 | E190,E190
41 | E170
42 | E190,E190
43 | ATR42
44 | ATR72,ATR72
```

No caso precise que ele não repita valores iguais (Como o E190, por exemplo).

Como trato essas incidências no Oracle Developer?

Comment: Olá Luan! Primeiramente eu aconselharia fazer a consulta sem o listagg, provavelmente deve existir valores duplicados, ai você teria que tratar na sua consulta para não repetir estes valores. Simulando o problema citado: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74fa1/3/0

Comment: Olá, amigo. Na tabela os valores não estavam duplicados. Chequei antes de fazer o LISTAGG. A solução do amigo abaixo criando uma tabela virtual funcionou! Muitíssimo obrigado pela contribuição! Abraço!!

Answer (score 0):

uma solução e fazer uma tabela virtual

```
SELECT PEH.PN,
LISTAGG (PEH.AC_TYPE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PEH.AC_TYPE DESC) AS 
"EFETIVIDADE"
FROM\
(SELECT DISTINCT  PEH.PN,PEH.AC_TYPE
FROM
ODB.PN_EFFECTIVITY_HEADER PEH) PEH
GROUP BY PEH.PN;
```

Comment: Amigo, muitíssimo obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente. Grande abraço!!

Comment: esta um colega me mostrou outro dia ... https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#wm_concat ...